# Keytab file authentication check

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, keytab

I have a query, I have created a user and generated keytab file from it but I want to test it with the credentials before sharing this file is there any way to achieve this, I know the username password and all the relevant information.

Comment: I lurk in this tag and I noticed that it seems whenever you ask a question, and people give you the answer, you don't mark their answer as answered, nor do you even comment back.  Do you understand how this site works?  You are coming here for free help, yet when people help, you don't respond.  That's pretty self-centered, goes against the spirit of the site, and doesn't put you in a good light.  I would highly suggest that you read [Ask].

Comment: Hi @JohnRSmith My apologies if you find my behavior self centered.
I will definitely try to comment from now onwards I tried upvoting the answer but I guess it isn't working for me .

Its giving below message : 

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example using kinit and klist to validate a keytab file named lisa.example.com.keytab for an account with SPN HTTP/lisa.example.com in the EXAMPLE.COM Kerberos realm.

```
root@4e06b32e1ca8:/usr/local/tomcat/conf# kinit -k -t ./lisa.example.com.keytab HTTP/lisa.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM 

root@4e06b32e1ca8:/usr/local/tomcat/conf# klist
 Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
 Default principal: HTTP/lisa.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM

 Valid starting Expires Service principal 
07/08/2017 18:27:38 07/09/2017 04:27:38 krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
 renew until 07/09/2017 18:27:38
```

Comment: Hi @LisaJ let me try what you have suggested I will come back with update.